# must be called with Obj instance (got tuple instead)

Tags: python

I'm having a class with 2 attributes , and I have a function that generates object from a tuple , but looks like Python refuses to pass a tuple as an argument 
here is the code :

```
class Obj(object): 
  def __init__ (self,x,y): 
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
  def divide (t):
    a=t[0]*2
    b=t[1]+t[2]
    return Obj(a,b)

r=(5,2)
o=Obj.divide(r)
print(o)
```

and here's the error

```
Traceback .......,line 12 , in <module> o=Obj.divide(r)
TypeError: unbound method divide() must be called with Obj instance as first argument (got tuple instance instead)
```

Comment: please fix indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you need to explicitly include `self` argument in method signature:

```
def divide(self ,t):
    pass # do your stuff
```

or if you want it to be a classmethod:

```
@classmethod
def divide(cls ,t):
    pass # do your stuff
```

PS. you have other errors in your code, but you should be able to figure them out on your own now...

Comment: it still asks for Obj instance as argument

Comment: actually it helped 
all I needed was to initialize o
`o=Obj(0,0)
r=(5,2)
o=Obj.divide(o,r)`

Comment: If you have object initialized, you may just `o.divide(r)`